# Google maps help placing markers

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, google-maps

Pretty new to PHP/Wordpress
I have looked in a million places but have found little to help me.  Im trying to load locations from a DB and display on a wordpress page (custom plugin Im making) and have then have the results mapped on a google maps instance.  Addresses have lat and long already.

I can get it load and display on the page, but will not place markers on map.  Any help would be appreciated.

Map instance

```
<script>
function initialize($Item)
{
var mapProp = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(53.548099, -113.522532),
  zoom:18,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map")
  ,mapProp);
echo ("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name</b><br/>$desc');\n");
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

DB work

```
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ //check if form was submitted

// Set variables
$data = array();
$input = $_POST['text']; //get input text
$table = $_POST['field']; //get Table
$org = $_POST['org'];

// Check if input is empty

if(!empty($input)){

// Debug line comment out
// echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('You Entered: ".$input." from ".$table." looking for ".$org."');</script>";

global $wpdb;

// Check if Organization set to all or something else
if ($_POST['org'] == "All") {

$feed = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from wp_NBDonation where $table     like '%{$input}%' order by Type;");
} else { 

$feed = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * from wp_NBDonation where $table     like '%{$input}%' and Type in('$org','Both');");
}

echo "<ul id='list'>";
// if 0 results display message
    if($feed==null){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No results found.');</script>";
    }else{

if( is_array( $feed ) && count( $feed ) > 0 ) {
foreach($feed as $item){
    $data[] = $feed;
    echo "<li id='item'>";
    echo "<h2>".$item->Type."<br>";
    echo $item->Name."</h2>";
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "<span id='head'>Address:</span><br>";
    echo $item->Address."<br>";
    echo $item->City." ".$item->State_Province."<br>";
    echo $item->Postalcode."<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<span id='head'>Phone:</span> ".$item->ContactNumber."  <br>";
    echo "<span id='head'>Email: </span> <a href='mailto:".$item->Email."?Subject=Donation Inquiry'>".$item->Email."  </a><br>";
    echo "<span id='head'>Website: </span> <a href='http://".$item->Website."'target=_blank>".$item->Website."</a><br>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<span id='head'>Instructions:</span><br>";
    echo $item->ContactInstructions."<br><br>";
    echo "<span id='head'>Payment Method: </span><br>";
    echo $item->PaymentMethod."<br>";
    echo "</li>";  // closes Item
    $lat=$Item->lat;
    $lon=$Item->lng;
    $name=$Item->Name;
    $desc=$Item->Type;

} // end ForEach
} // end if array
} // end if null
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert(print_r($data));</script>";

?>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You only said what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I can get it load and display on the page, but will not place markers on map.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the `AddMarker()` function that's inside of `initialize` is referencing.

The [Google Maps API reference for Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) suggests two ways to create markers:

1. using `new google.maps.Marker()`  inside your initialization
   function
2. using `var marker = new google.maps.Marker()` outside your initialization function and then calling `marker.setMap()`